# Redirecting to specific slug from textfield in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am totally new to ember so please be nice :)

I have an Ember app where i want to redirect to a specific slug taken from an textfield input. In my .hbs i have the following code:

```
<div class="liquid-container">
  <div class="liquid-child">
    <div class="desktop-layout-scroll-container">
      <div class="overlay-info-layout">
        <div class="overlay-info-layout-content">
          <h1 class="expired-overlay-status">{{t 'code.title'}}</h1>
          <h2 class="expired-overlay-explanation">
            {{t 'code.description'}}<br>
          </h2>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
              <input name="txtSlug" type="text" id="txtSlug" class="field" />            
              <input type="submit" name="btnGo" value="" id="btnGo" class="btn" onclick="javascript:SubmitForm()" />
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitForm(){
        var Slugtxt = document.getElementById("txtSlug").value;
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/" + Slugtxt;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You doing it soo wrong... Don't want to be mean or rude, but please, read official [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/) before writing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never embed JavaScript in an Ember .hbs file. This code should really go in your controller for this class. First, generate your controller:

```
ember g controller <name_of_route>
```

Then inside your controller, you want to define two things. The slugtxt variable, and the redirecting as an action. That would look something like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  slugtxt: '',

  actions: {
    redirect() {
      window.location = "http://www.google.com/" + this.get('slugtxt');
    }
  }
}
```

Then, back in your template, you would want to change your input to be mapped to the `slugtxt` variable from your controller, and set the action of the button to the `redirect` action that you defined in your controller. That would look something like this:

```
{{input value=slugtxt}}
<button {{action "redirect"}}>Submit</button>
```

No need to worry about using the `<input>` tag, you generally wont be using form data with ember.

Comment: Hi Tom. Finally got time to get around your solution. 
I get the following error when i try to use your code:

controllers/index.js: line 9, col 54, 'slugtxt' is not defined.

Comment: Hey, there was a typo in my response which I edited a fix for. Try the code now.